# Calculate ellipse semi-axises from center point on Earth given distance

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

How would one calculate the vertices of an ellipse on the surface of the Earth given a center coordinate and a distance (in KM)? Since the distance between two points in the Y (Latitude) direction get closer as one approaches the poles, when generating a "buffer" around a point, the buffer becomes an ellipse and not a perfect circle. As such I need to calculate the semi-major and semi-minor axis values to determine the vertices.

Not sure of the formulas for such a task

Comment: If I read the question correctly the figure you want is a circle: the set of points a fixed (great circle) distance from a fixed point. Distance on the surface of the Earth is independent of latitude, although finding an equation for points on that circle isn't.

Comment: Correct. However, how does one determine the terminal points in the X/Y directions from a fixed point? I know great circle to be used in the calculation of the distance between two fixed points on Earth (Haversine).

Comment: @pstatix Can you add a sketch of what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Calculating buffers on the Earth's surface is not as easy as it may seem. An accurate solution would involve equations like [Vincenty's formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae).

That said, if you are willing to accept some inaccuracies, much simpler and less time-consuming formulae exist. 
For example, assuming your distances are fairly short, and not too close to a pole, you could simply use $\frac{s}{r{\text{ cos }}\phi}$ ($\phi =$ latitude, $s =$ buffer distance and $r =$ 6371 km) as a semi major-axis, and $s/r$ as a semi minor-axis, multiply these 2 results by $180/\pi$ and the resulting "ellipse" (analog to [Tissot's indicatrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tissot%27s_indicatrix)) on the lat-lon square grid (called plate carree equirectangular projection) would give you an approximation of the actual buffer, which could then be used to generate lat/lon coordinates for other vertices. It works fairly well for shorts distances (ex. a 5 km buffer typically gives an max error around 20 meters), however, for a distance of, say, 1000 km, the max error can be as large as several tens of km, and more if the buffer is close to the poles.
The [haversine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) and [spherical trigonometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry) method is another way to solve the problem, with errors no larger than 0.5% for any length.

So the method to choose depends on your specific project / application. However, if you do need good accuracy, you might not want to program long formulae like Vincenty's. Some GIS programs like QGIS, ArcGIS already have those built-in algorithms that can generate geodesic buffers. Other solutions are available online, for example, with python [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vincenty/0.1.4) from which you could build with.